# Size of a blob field in Firebird

Tags: firebird

Is there a way to retrieve (using a select statement) the size of a blob field in Firebird??

I've a field called "data" and I'd like to know the total size of all the records in the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can use the [OCTET_LENGTH()](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-octet_length.html) function.

You should also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699921/how-can-i-measure-the-amount-of-space-taken-by-blobs-on-a-firebird-2-1-database/3712136#3712136) answer it should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If the field contains Images or another kind of data or even Text, you can use F_BLOBSIZE(blobfield) from [FreeAdHocUDF](http://freeadhocudf.org/index_eng.html)

Input   BLOB    TextBLOb
For TextBLOb: returns the size/length (similar F_STRINGLENGTH)
For BinarBLOb: returns the size of file in byte

Comment: What is better F_BLOBSIZE or OCTET_LENGTH?

Comment: @hellboy: OCTET_LENGTH for Firebird 2.1 and up, F_BLOBSIZE for Firebird 2.0 and below. See [the Firebird documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-octet_length.html) for more details